# Doesn't Create Libs Directory After ndk-build command in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, libpcap, ndk-build

I am a newer in using android studio ndk.
I make a jni direcotry and this direcotry contains an libpcap library , I want compile and make .so file but I don't know why after using ndk-build command , doesn't create libs direcotry also the obj directory is made.
But when I remove the libpcap library the libs directory is made.
Also when it is being compiled , this library has many too warning 
How I can solve this problem?

Comment: I solved this error , but I have another error, this error says , couldn't load libray why?

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load libpcap from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[dexPath=/data/app/com.parp.jni-2.apk,libraryPath=/data/app-lib/com.parp.jni-2]: findLibrary returned null

Comment: I solved this problem with this   externalNativeBuild {
        ndkBuild {
            path '../jni/Android.mk'
        }
    } in the build.gradle